# Unresolved Symbol Errors for C++/CLI dll in C++ Project

Tags: c++, dll, c++-cli

I am trying a very simple implementation of a C++/CLI wrapper to allow legacy C++ code to reference .Net code, as [described here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2008/02/16/net-to-c-bridge/). I am getting stuck just trying to get my basic C++/CLI unmanaged (native) objects linked, without even including any managed/IL/.Net code.

My question is, following along with this basic setup and what I describe below, am I right to be very confused about these errors? Are there some considerations that I'm missing? Maybe the answer is that this should work, so it's not clear what's wrong. That's still helpful. A similar working example would be great.

**Unresolved Symbol Errors**

> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __thiscall Wrapper::Test::Test(void)"
>   (__imp_??0Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  NativeApp
>
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __thiscall Wrapper::Test::~Test(void)"
>   (__imp_??1Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  NativeApp

I've reviewed related questions on SO without any luck. I've got my dll header included in the client C++ project, my project reference to the C++/CLI wrapper dll, and my define statements for import/export. My very simple code is shown below. I am not using any MFC. **I am using VS2017**. `DumpBin.exe /exports` shows export symbols that seem to match what the linker error says are missing.

```
      1    0 000010D0 ??0Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ = ??0Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Wrapper::Test::Test(void))
      2    1 000010E0 ??1Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ = ??1Test@Wrapper@@QAE@XZ (public: __thiscall Wrapper::Test::~Test(void))
      3    2 000010C0 ??4Test@Wrapper@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z = ??4Test@Wrapper@@QAEAAV01@ABV01@@Z (public: class Wrapper::Test & __thiscall Wrapper::Test::operator=(class Wrapper::Test const &))
```

Here's the basic code...

## NativeApp.exe (project)

---

**NativeApp.cpp** (File)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Wrapper.h" //From additional includes directory

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Program Started" << std::endl;
    Wrapper::Test shell = Wrapper::Test::Test(); //Use dll
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

**Reference to Wrapper**

[image]

---

## Wrapper.dll (Project)

---

***Wrapper.cpp*** (File)

```
#include "Wrapper.h"

#pragma unmanaged
namespace Wrapper {
    Test::Test() {
    }
    Test::~Test() {
    }
}
```

***Wrapper.h*** (File)

```
#pragma once

#ifdef WRAPPER_EXPORTS  
#define WRAPPER_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define WRAPPER_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

#pragma unmanaged
namespace Wrapper {
    class WRAPPER_API Test {
    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
    };
}
```

---

Comment: Why the downvote? Seriously, it would be helpful to know why? I see lots of related questions on SO so there is a precedent for the topic and yet this question is unique in its details.

Comment: While the underlying idea (use C++/CLI as a layer between .NET and C++ code) is quite solid, basically all the details of your approach are wrong.  `__declspec(dllexport)` is not used by C++/CLI and does not generate the .NET metadata needed by C#.  `#pragma unmanaged` results in things that can only be accessed by other C++ code (it *is* possible for that other C++ code to be seen from C#).  To make C#-usable objects, you need to use `public ref class` on the C++/CLI side.

Comment: The reverse is also true.  `#pragma unmanaged` code can't use .NET stuff, it can only call other C++ code (that C++ code can use `#pragma managed` and .NET).  For what you describe (wrapping calls to C# inside a main application written in C++) there's no reason to use a DLL.  Just link the C++ and C++/CLI files together into the EXE.

Comment: If you remove the `__declspec` stuff, and change the project reference to ["link library dependencies"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTlHe.png), your sharing of native C++ objects should start working.

Comment: The dumpbin output shows the constructor and destructor of a class named NativeShell.  How that turned into "Test" in the code snippet is impossible to guess.

Comment: @HansPassant That was my mistake copying to here, I corrected it above. I changed the class name recreating the entire setup again to double check my setup, but same result. I placed this second version on github. The actual dumpbin /export names do match the error names.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks for your input, appreciated. I only mention the C# wrapper side of things to make sense of using `/clr` but then only using `dllexport` and `unmanaged`. As you point out, I cut out the parts that are managed and IL, the code I posted is purposefully scope limited to C++ to isolate the problem I'm facing, which is linking as a `/clr` compiled dll to pure C++ project. Yes, I've thought about trying the static .lib approach, but it doesn't really satisfy my full requirements. I would like to get the .dll to work.

Comment: @u8it: I don't know what you think you are accomplishing by using a DLL, but there are severe restrictions associated with putting `__declspec(dllexport)` on a class.  `__declspec(dllexport) extern "C"` on functions is highly useful, it enabled decoupling and reuse.  But when you export a class, the compiler versions and compile settings have to match on both sides.  Combine it with delay-loading and you can have slightly improved startup times (but it just moves the work later, no overall efficiency improvement).

Comment: @BenVoigt I tried avoiding mangling by using `extern "C"`, good suggestion, but it did not help. Not using a dll is a separate design decision for a development team. For me, the main issue is that this should be possible with a dll, so I'm keeping the dll constraint on the question. I was able to resolve the problem though and posted the answer. I hope it helps anyone else facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was under the impression that the project reference took care of any additional dependency settings behind the scenes. Apparently, that is not the case. The .lib file needed to be added as an additional dependency, [as is described here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Compiler/Linker/Libraries/Configuring_Visual_Studio). However, as [described by this Microsoft document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx), everything worked without additional dependencies when I was using non `/clr` dlls, so I'm not sure why the additional dependency was only required for my CLR reference. Clearly, I need to read up on this some more.

In any case, my C++ client project requirements are listed below. I was missing the second requirement. Also, [here is an example project](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/) that helped me diagnose the problem.

**1.) Add project reference**

[image]

**2.) Add the .lib file as an `Additional Dependency.**

[image]

[Optional] Use `Additional Library Directories`

[image]

**3.) `#include` .h file in code where appropriate**

[image]

[Optional] Use additional include directories

[image]

## EDIT: Why the additional dependency was required, and alternative option

As noted above, I was getting hung up on why the .lib additional dependency was required for the /clr dll but not for the non-clr dll. The answer is because a /clr project is configured by default to ignore import libraries. So when the project gets referenced by another C++ project, the project reference ignores import libraries. Changing this setting (Linker > General > Ignore Import Libraries) to "No" in the /clr dll project solves the issue so that the additional dependency is not required and the project reference works the same as the non-clr C++ dll.

Comment: CLR references use .NET metadata, which as we previously discussed, doesn't cover the native exports.  Glad you got it working, but be careful that when exporting classes, the compiler version, runtime library version, and compile settings have to match.  Nothing is decoupled.

Comment: I tried to follow these instructions but I continued to get the LNK2019 error.  Differences:  I am using VS2022, and I was calling a static method in my C++/CLI wrapper (taken from other examples - I assumed it would make things easier too!).  I finally got the error to go away by (1) following these directions and (2) adding __cdecl to the static member function signature in the C++/CLI .h and .cpp files.   LNK2019 gone!  ... I hope this solution is stable: this took me DAYS to sort out.